# "OnClick" Ajax function on ''IMAP to PHP page''

Tags: php, ajax

Everything works fine, but i need one more function. On every newmail, in same line i need button "OWNER", so when user input his inicials in that field, field will be locked so anybody can know who own which mail.

```
/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'X';
$password = 'X';
/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');
/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {        
        /* begin output var */
        $output = '';        
        /* put the newest emails on top */
        rsort($emails);        
        /* for every email... */
        foreach($emails as $email_number) {                
                /* get information specific to this email */
                $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
                $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);                
                /* output the email header information */
                $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
                $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
                $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
                $output.= '</div>';

        }        
        echo $test , $test , $output;
}
imap_close($inbox);
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. What does "own which mail" mean? Who's anybody? Right now you only grab emails and display them. No Users. Any DB/Storage there??

Comment: Let's say that you and me work together but we are not in same room (so we can't talk) and e-mail arrives. When e-mail arrives, we can't both reply on same, we must split them, you will take one, i will take another. We can do that if on every grabbed mail on that page empty field "user" is displayed, in which i can put my inicials or you can put yours, so we will know who will reply on which mail.