# Ajax script is not updating PHP file and his var value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is simple form, on click i need calculated value to be displayed in file process.php, but this is not working for me. It seems that "click" on "=" don't do anything, in process.php there is default value "0", no results.

```
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js">
$('#button').click(function() {
    var val1 = $('#text1').val();
    var val2 = $('#text2').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'demo/process.php',
        data: { text1: val1, text2: val2 },
        success: function(response) {
            $('#result').html(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="text1"> +
<input type="text" id="text2">
<button id="button"> = </button>

<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

AND PHP

```
<?php
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];
echo $text1 + $text2;
?>
```

Comment: the issue is that the javascript is running before the button is in the DOM - move your javascript AFTER the button, OR, wrap your code in jQueries ubiquitous document ready wrapper

Comment: Still not working...

Comment: What have you changed

Comment: Check developer tools network tab to see what is being sent and received in the request

Comment: in "body" first i put html code for button, below that i put script

Comment: @FabianCannes there are many things wrong in your code, have you tried my example?

Comment: @Thibaut, yes, it's working m8,thx. I have one more question to add, how can i save entered values (php var value) permanently on that php file?

Comment: @FabianCannes If you want to save permanently variables, you would need a database to save them and request them later on. If your question is answered don't forget to check the green mark to the left of my answer! ;)

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that i vote it correctly .

Comment: @FabianCannes you sure did and welcome to Stack.

Comment: p.s. I hope that you guy's can help me with this topic    --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035620/onclick-ajax-function-on-imap-to-php-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, are you using a php server?

if you do then try this (yes i used a different library):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="text1" /> 
            <input type="text" id="text2" />
            <button type="button" id="button"> = </button>
        </form>

        <div id="result"></div>    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#button').click(function() {
                var val1 = $('#text1').val();
                var val2 = $('#text2').val();

                $.post( "demo/process.php", {text1: val1, text2: val2} ,     function(data){
                    $('#result').html(data);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

in php:

```
<?php
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];
echo $text1 + $text2;
?>
```

**Tip:** Always specify the type attribute for a  element. Different browsers use different default types for the  element.

Comment: why would you suggest a GET instead of a POST? besieds, `#button` will still be undefined regardless of the code running in the click callback

Comment: @JaromandaX this would work with POST as well, but why not get as you redirect to a different page?

Comment: there is no form in the question .. what are you talking about?